# using df command in Linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to programmaticly check the remaining space in a linux server using 'df -h' command. I am asking if there is any way to use df command to return the overall remaing space in one line instead of showing the remaining space sorted by filesysetm name ?

Comment: I guess you have to clarify your question. 'remaining space' of what? a root fs? a mounted sd card? some mounted network folder? free space is is too broad concept. try maybe `--total` -  _elide all entries insignificant to available space, and produce a grand total_, something like `df -h --total | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $4 }'`

Comment: I mean the physical storage in the machine. without any mounted network folders.